# Limit maximum choices in multi-answer Google Forms question

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a Google form and want to restrict a person's maximum choices to 6 in one of the more than one answer type questions.
Can someone please help me with this?

PS -I tried to use the Form choice limiter but it turns out that it just sets limit on the number of people who can answer the question.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. For help on Google Docs, please post on Stack Exchange for help on the use of online services, or contact Google Support for help on your topic.

Comment: `want to restrict a person's maximum choices to 6 in one of the more than one answer type questions` I don't think this is a feature offered in Google Sheets.

Comment: `I am creating a Google form and want to restrict a person's maximum choices to 6 in one of the more than one answer type questions.` This is unclear and/or ambiguous but surely this depends on Form design and how many options are offered in each question. Only one type - `Checkboxes` - accepts more than one option and this type offers `Response validation` to require `at least`, `at most` or `exactly` a given number of options. Would you please edit the question to provide more specific information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I wanted to restrict the maximum number of responses to 6 . The response validation feature as suggested by Tedinoz did help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ Tedinoz ,the response validation feature may be used to restrict the maximum number of responses to a particular question
Big thanks to @ Tedinoz for helping me with it

@ Andrew will surely keep in mind your suggestion when asking questions.